# Pull async does not work if local DB has been seeded on app 1st run

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

When performing pull async on azure SQL data from a Xamarin Forms app I notice the following:

If the local DB is empty initially, data is pulled no problem from azure.

Further rows added in azure are pulled no problem.

Rows added locally are pushed no problem.

However, if I seed the local DB the first time the app is run, with some of the same data that is in azure (same id's also) then the sync does not seem to work, breakpoint I put in my node.js back end are not hit - the C# app code hits the line where the pull async is done but does not complete.

The node.js update (to the Azure Sql DB) seems to fail  with

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'.

Is this expected behaviour, and should I refrain from seeding locally if I want the sync to work correctly?

Comment: `If the local DB is empty initially, data is pulled no problem from azure.` which data?

Comment: `Rows added locally are pushed no problem.` what's locally?

Comment: `However, if I seed the local DB the first time the app is run, with some of the same data that is in azure (same id's also) then the sync does not seem to work`: possibly an exception is thrown; try to find it and to fix it... probably something with same id's

Comment: By locally I mean the SQLite DB used by the app, this should sync with an Azure SQL Server DB, sorry if that was not clear

Comment: No problem, that's why I asked. I think, the issue is due to duplicate keys. But that depends n your setup. Maybe natural keys will help you: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html

Comment: No exceptions that I can find, and the id's (guids) have to be the same as far as I can tell, so the SDK knows what needs updated

Comment: Ah... hmm... it surprises me. As for now I think we need more info.

Answer (score 1):

When you "seed" data the problem is that some meta data is created in the table that is out of your control (I would guess it is some sort of column with last sync number or id, possibly something else too). If it gets in the conflict with meta data on the server (and obviously it does in your case) the sync won't work out of the box (you may need to do some additional work to handle the conflicts).